# How to check user is connected to MySQL server?

Tags: mysql

In MS SQL, I can check user status on server with proc sp_who @loginame='user', so what query to get user status on mySQL?

Comment: please be more specific. you cannot ask questions like these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### "Vanilla" way

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

This will bring back a result set with the `User` who's running what process in MySQL.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

#### "Custom" way

If you want to show everyone connected (host, user, number of connections), use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(host, ':', 1) AS host_short,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT USER)   AS users,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   information_schema.processlist
GROUP  BY host_short
ORDER  BY COUNT(*),
          host_short;
```

- [Source](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2011/08/how-to-easily-see-whos-connected-to.html)

- You can also do it by specific database, by adding `WHERE db = ''`
- You can find non-sleeping accounts by adding `WHERE command != 'Sleep'`
- You can get just a specific user by adding `WHERE user = 'root'`

#### I need get all user is connecting to mySQL server with root account, do you have any idea?

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.processlist
WHERE user = 'root'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SHOW processlist;` command:

It will show something like this:

```
| Id   | User     | Host        | db        | Command | Time | State | Info  |
+------+----------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------+------+
| 1419 | root | localhost:60014 | test      | Sleep   |  446 |       | NULL
```

And you will know how many connections has every user, what database are using... etc

Comment: Hi Sal00m, I need get all user is connecting to mySQL server with root account, do you have any idea ?

Comment: As @hd says in the other answer, new versions of MySQL supports `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST`, so you can use `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE user = 'root'` to count the number of users using root user